# Understanding of non-degeneracy and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

My class version of the non-degeneracy definition states:

*Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\Bbb F$, equipped with a symmetric bilinear form $b : V \times V → \Bbb F$ . Then $b$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form if $~∀\,u∈V,\ b(v,u)=0 \implies v=0$.*

I find myself confused when I try to apply it to proving all inner products are non-degenerate, and here is my confusion:

Given an inner product $b$. I let $u \in V$ and assume $b(v,u)=0$ and I am trying to show $v=0$.

I saw on a few texts that we are allowed to pick $v$ so that $v=u$ and thus we get $v=0$ from positivity. Why are we allowed to choose the value for $v$? I thought $v$ could just be any arbitrary vector and it doesn't have to happen to be $u$. To make it clearer, it doesn't make sense to me that $b(v,u)=0\Rightarrow v=u$ whatsoever. In my mind $v$ is fixed and does not vary with $u$.

Could someone kindly explain what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Yes you seem a bit confused.  $b(v,u) = 0 \Rightarrow v=u$ does not make sense and isn't true. Where'd you get that from?

Comment: Sorry man I had a typo in my post but I get it now thanks anyways!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find it easier to think of this: the *radical* of $V$ with respect to a (symmetric, if you may) bilinear form $b: V \times V \to \Bbb C$ is the subspace: $${\rm Rad}(V) = \{ u \in V \mid b(u,v) = 0,~\forall\,v \in V \}$$
We say that $b$ is non-degenerate on $V$ if ${\rm Rad}(V) = \{0\}$. Like a sort of kernel.

Now suppose that $b$ is an inner product, and take $u \in {\rm Rad}(V)$. So $b(u,v) = 0$ for all $v \in V$. Well, $u \in V$, so you can say that $b(u,u) = 0$. Now follows from the defintion of inner product (definite positivity) that $u = 0$. So ${\rm Rad}(V) = \{0\}$ and $b$ is non-degenerate on $V$.

---

Remark: to be precise, as I have written it, ${\rm Rad}(V)$ is the kernel of the linear map $V \ni u \mapsto b(u,\cdot) \in V^\ast$. You can ignore this, in any case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still don't fully understand. what if $v\ne u$ yet $b(u,v)=0$, in this case I cannot conclude $u=0$ and $u$ could be something else.

Comment: If $v \neq u$ and $b(u,v)=0$ you can't conclude that $u = 0$, correct. But this doesn't mean that $u \neq 0$ either. You can conclude that $u = 0$ by choosing $v= u$. You can make this choice because $b(u,v)=0$ **for all** $v \in V$.

Comment: You are not choosing/varying $u$. The vector $u$ is fixed. We fixed it in the start. For the sake of the explanation, suppose we have a list of vectors that you can choose to put in the spot $b(u, \cdot) = 0$: $$\ldots, x,y,w,\color{red}{u}, r, s,\ldots$$Aha! That one'll give me the "$b(u,u) = 0 \implies u = 0$" that I want.

Comment: Okay I think I am more convinced now. The idea that other choices for $v$ doesn't give any information except for being equal to $u$ is really mind-opening. Thanks man!

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the symmetric bilinear form
\begin{align}
\langle,\rangle:\ \mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2&\longrightarrow\mathbb R
\\ (x,y)&\longmapsto\langle x,y\rangle=x_1y_1
\end{align}
Then $\langle,\rangle$ is a inner product. But it is degenerate.